# How do I block by block sum values in a column that match a given condition using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
    a     b(a>1)
0   1.1   true
1   1.2   true
2   0.9   false
3   1.2   true
4   1.3   true
5   0.8   false
6   0.9   false
```

The result should be [2.3, 0.9, 2.5, 1.7] which means [1.1 + 1.2, 0.9, 1.1+1.3, 0.8 + 0.9].

Comment: Something like `df.groupby(df['b(a>1)'].ne(df['b(a>1)'].shift()).cumsum())['a'].sum().tolist() `

Comment: If I change to "df.groupby(df['b(a>1)'].ne(df['b(a>1)'].shift()).cumprod())['a'].prod().tolist()", the sentence generates a list of 2 elements but not 4.